# How to remove all rows where cells are blank in specific column name

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code below which does not currently work.

It is supposed to delete all rows where values are blank in Column BI in Sheet 1. However, I would like it to delete all rows where cells are blank for Column where A1 cell is equal to "DATA_TYPE".

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Columns("BI:BI").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

How can I change this to do what I am after? At the moment, I am getting some strange output message back stating "400" and I have no idea what it means...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, that's good but how can I get it to do it by locating the name of the column from Cell A1 = "DATA_TYPE" rather than BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Sub DeletedBlankCells()
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="DATA_TYPE", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(Rng.EntireColumn.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm I am getting a debug error - Rng.EntireColumn.Address = <Object variable or With block variable not set>

Comment: @Porkball21 My bad - it's fixed now

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm